# Write json content in json format to a new file in Node js

Tags: node.js, json, fs

Goal: To write the file content in json format using Node js. Upon opening the file manually, content should be displayed in json format

I tried both `fs-extra` module functions - `outputJsonSync` or `writeFileSync` to write json content to a file. They write the content inline as below

```
{"a":"1", "b":"2"}
```

However, I would like to see the content as below when I open the file manually:

```
{
"a" : "1",
"b" : "2"
}
```

I tried [jsome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsome) and [pretty-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-data) on the data as follows:

```
fs.outputJsonSync(jsome(data))
fs.outputJsonSync(pd.json(data))
```

They also write data inline only with extra `\` or `\n` and `tabs` added to the data but doesn't open in formatted style.

Any inputs are highly appreciated. Thanks!

[Update]

Other scenario:

```
const obj = {"a":"1", "b":"2"}
var string = "abc" + "splitIt" + obj
doSomething(string)
```

And inside the function implementation:

```
doSomething(string){
var arr =  string.split("splitIt")
var stringToWrite = JSON.stringify(arr[1], null, '  ').replace(/: "(?:[^"]+|\\")*"$/, ' $&')
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, stringToWrite)
}
```

Following output is displayed when I open the file:

```
"[object Object]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the object, you can specify a replacer function to separate each key-value pair by a newline, then use a regular expression to trim the leading spaces, then use another regular expression to insert a space before the `:` of a key-value pair. Then, just write the formatted string to a file:

```js
const obj = {"a":"1", "b":"2"};
const stringToWrite = JSON.stringify(obj, null, ' ')
  // Trim leading spaces:
  .replace(/^ +/gm, '')
  // Add a space after every key, before the `:`:
  .replace(/: "(?:[^"]+|\\")*",?$/gm, ' $&');
console.log(stringToWrite);
```

Though, you may find the leading spaces more readable:

```js
const obj = {"a":"1", "b":"2"};
const stringToWrite = JSON.stringify(obj, null, '  ')
  // Add a space after every key, before the `:`:
  .replace(/: "(?:[^"]+|\\")*",?$/gm, ' $&');
console.log(stringToWrite);
```

Comment: When I try stringToWrite using fs - `fs.outputFileSync(filePath, stringToWrite)`, I still see the data inline with extra slashes upon opening the new file that got created

Comment: Works just fine with `writeFileSync`. All the newlines present in `stringToWrite` are still there, and there are no slashes.

Comment: It looks to work with `outputFileSync` as well. I cannot reproduce your problem. Please double-check

Comment: Thanks! This works fine withthe given example. My actual scenario is I am appending the object (obj) to a string to pass it to my function accepts only single argument. And later inside the function I am using split to get to the actual data - obj. When I use this, I only see [Object Object] in the file. Edited the question to be clear

Comment: With your new code, `arr[1]` is a *string*, not an object, so `JSON.stringify(arr[1]...` doesn't make any sense - and, being a string already, the plain string content alone should be the result, not `object Object`. Are you sure that the code you posted is the code you're actually using? It doesn't appear to be (need a [MCVE] to replicate the problem)

Comment: For example, an input string of `foo splitIt bar` results in `" bar"` being written to the fiile.

Comment: I am trying the same data as my actual scenario is similar to this. Actually, `console.log("abc" + " splitIt " + obj)` [where `obj = {"a":"1", "b":"2"}`] prints `abc splitIt [Object Object]` on console. This same value is sent as argument to `doSomething`. So split basically returns `abc` and `[Object Object]`. This explains why I see `"[Object Object]"` in the written file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186752/discussion-between-newuser-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 3):

JSON.stringify, has two optional parameters, the first one being a replacer function, the second one(What you want) is for spacing.

```
const obj = {"a":"1", "b":"2"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))
```

This will give you:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2"
}
```